# Chart.js - combine data and label into a single object

Tags: chart.js

I am integrating chart.js into my application and to me it does not seem possible to pass an object as the data with the keys as labels.

Right now I am trying this with a regular bar chart, in which the API looks like:

```
data : [1,2,3]
labels: ['a','b','c']
```

The docs allow passing something like the below:

`data: [{x:'2016-12-25', y:20}, {x:'2016-12-26', y:10}]`

But only when using a time scale.

My arrays are coming from elsewhere and could easily lose their order, I would like to pass something such as:

`data: [{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is like `[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3}]` you can easily convert it to two arrays using

```
let labelArr=[];let dataArr=[];
data.forEach((item)=>{labelArr.push(Object.keys(item) 
[0]);dataArr.push(item[Object.keys(item)[0]])})
```

This is the handily possible way, As the current API of chart.js is not having support for complex data array only alternative is to extend Chart.controller.bar from chartjs internal and then assign the same label array to it by extracting.

Comment: Appreciate the reply, I was avoiding the manipulation of the data too much. But extending the component seems like a good solution. However I will move c3.js because of this. Can you update your answer stating that this is not possible with the current API and I will set it as correct.

Comment: Updated the answer anyhow I am not promoting it but if you are looking for options of other API you can checkout highcharts also. It offers a lot more variety and less complexity than stock d3

Answer (score 0):

```
let data =   [1,2,3],
labels=['a','b','c'];

labels.forEach((item,index)=>{
data[index]={[item]:data[index]}
})

  console.log(data); //[{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }, { c: 3 }]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.